# What is the relationship between zlib and minizip?

Tags: c++, zip, zlib

What is the relationship between [zlib](https://zlib.net/) and minizip? When I download zlib I see minizip visual studio project as a part of the zlibvc solution in the windows enviroment.

[image]

1. Not sure are these two different libraries or one is a component of other.
2. If two different what is the use case of each

Comment: Did you read the readme file in the win32 directory, or open the minizip.c file? If you had, it would lead you here: http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I check on zlib [FAQ](https://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html):

> Q: I'm having a problem with the zip functions in zlib, can you help?
>
> A: There are no zip functions in zlib. You are probably using minizip by Giles Vollant, which is found in the contrib directory of zlib. It is not part of zlib. In fact none of the stuff in contrib is part of zlib. The files in there are not supported by the zlib authors. You need to contact the authors of the respective contribution for help.

And the next one:

> Q: Can zlib handle .zip archives?
>
> A: Not by itself, no. See the directory contrib/minizip in the zlib distribution.

So from above Q&A we can deduce that **minizip is used by zlib to handle .zip** files.

Comment: Probably the opposite is true: "minizip uses zlib to handle .zip files"?

Answer (score 3):

minizip is a set of zip and unzip routines that use zlib and process zip-format files that use the deflate and store compression methods. minizip is not part of zlib, but is included in the zlib distribution as a third-party contribution in the contrib directory.

There are other zip libraries out there (that also use zlib), such as libzip and libarchive.

Answer (score 2):

From a dependencies point of view, **minizip uses zlib** to support *compressed* archives.

When you create a ZIP file, there are two distinct steps involved:

- Archiving: Packaging multiple files into a single one. (minizip)
- Compression (zLib)

One does not necessarily depend on the other. (E.g. you can compress only a single file without archiving, or you can create a non-compressed archive.)